# Implicit join using update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to update the values of a column in table X so that they are equal to those in table `Y` based on a primary key. I'm using an update statement, but I believe I'm doing something very wrong because I get the following error message:

> "Multi-part identifier could not be bound'.

```
update [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2] 
set Video_Name=[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1] 
where [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1].Updated_Campaign=[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2].Updated_Campaign
```

Comment: use tablename.column name in your query

Comment: Can you provide your tried query

Comment: Posting your query would significantly make this question easier to answer.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin same result :(

Comment: You seem to be setting the value of **column** `Video_Name` to the value of **table** `[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1]`. You need to use the value of another column. I also recommend uses aliases and `JOIN`s. So something more like `UPDATE A SET [Col1] = B.Col2 FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.fID;`

Comment: "update based on a primary key" doesn't clearly explain what you want, and other than that you have only given wrong code. So why do you expect us to know what you want? For code questions give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join

```
  update im  
    set im.Video_Name=im2.Video_Name
    from [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2] im join
     [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1] im2 
 on im.Updated_Campaign=im2.Updated_Campaign
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating via a CTE is one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    -- not sure about the t2 replacement column name.  I assume Video_Name here
    SELECT t1.Video_Name, t2.Video_Name AS Video_Name_New
    FROM [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2] t1
    INNER JOIN [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1] t2
        ON t1.Updated_Campaign = t2.Updated_Campaign
)

UPDATE cte
SET Video_Name = Video_Name_New;
```

I see multiple problems with your syntax, but the biggest problem I see is that you don't actually specify a column from the second table to be used in the update.

Comment: Hi Tim, yeah I forgot that but it still doesn't solve the problem; your code updates table 1 though, am I wrong?

Comment: @Jurij it would, yes.

Comment: I can't edit my answer further just based on your comment.  Maybe add table structure for both tables to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
update [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2]
set [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2].Video_Name=[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1] 
where [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1].Updated_Campaign=[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2].Updated_Campaign
```

add the table name before column name...

Answer (score 0):

I m guessing `[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1]` is a tablename. You need to pass column name in Set expression as below consider above mentioned table also have `Video_Name` column:

```
update [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2] 
set Video_Name=[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1].Video_Name 
where [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 WEEK1].Updated_Campaign=[UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-01-31 W2].Updated_Campaign
```